# Should the QOH in Stock Items (IN202500) decrease after shipment in Acumatica?

Tags: acumatica

I have recently noticed that the field "Qty On Hand" in stock items (IN202500) under the Warehouse Details tab only decreased when the order has been invoiced. I am guessing this have something to do with the fact that the stock is being moved to the  location. But isn't this incorrect since the stock would have been moved out of the warehouse from the shipment phase - hence why wait for the invoice part to occur? Does anybody have an explanation as to why it works this way? or whether it is a bug?

Thanks,
G

Comment: Do 'Confirm' > 'Update IN' in shippment to update the QuantityOnHand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quantity on hand will be updated only when the shipment has been confirmed, and the inventory issue document (IN Issue) has been released. Until then, the quantities will be held in a special bucket called SO Shipped.

Posting of the IN Issue occurs automatically when you release the invoice, but you can also force it to open by going to the shipment and doing Actions->Update IN

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, is there a certain config that would force it to Update IN immediately after confirming the shipment document (before releasing the invoice)?

Comment: Why do you want to do it right away? It means that you will have no possibility to edit quantities or correct shipment document after. I have never done it myself but automation steps can be configured to run the action automatically after Confirm Shipment.

Comment: I understood it as: confirming the shipment was final anyway, so the stock should have been decreased at that moment, the next invoicing step would only take care of the financials then.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do u want but here is hint you can do pre-invoice (quote invoice) and when move out of warehouse complete invoice and decrease QOH.